# Really Basic Parallax Scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm wanting to introduce parallax onto a website I'm developing but at a really low level. I've tried a lot of tutorials but they all seem to be geared towards websites with multiple full-window backgrounds.

Essentially what I have is a three column page with a static background throughout the site. I want the middle column (which happens to be an image) to scroll slightly slower then the left and right columns.

Any tips on the best and simplest way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: parallax scrolling vertically or horizontally?

Comment: vertically ideally. Though I'm open for horizontal as well either way works just as well in the design.

Comment: Found this: [jQuery scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/) and is not geared towards website with fullscreen backgrounds. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery plugin -- dead simple.
http://www.devinrolsen.com/jquery-zlayers-parallax-plugin/